# Django 3.2 - raw-SQL-Query with same table (Model)

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

We have migrated some database-tables from our productiv environment to the django ORM and auto sync this tables outside of django. → This works well so far, but we have troubles in django to connect this tables (Models) correctly to each other.

## models.py

```
class SsdaSdgadr(models.Model):
    sda_sdgid = models.ForeignKey(SsdgSendung, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    sda_satid = models.CharField(max_length=4, blank=True, null=True)
    sda_adrid = models.ForeignKey(SadrAdresse, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    sda_ref = models.CharField(max_length=35, blank=True, null=True)
    sda_termbis = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    sda_termvon = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'ssda_sdgadr'
        unique_together = (('sda_sdgid', 'sda_satid'),)

class SsdgSendung(models.Model):
    sdg_sdgid = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=30)
    sdg_konz = models.CharField(max_length=12, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'ssdg_sendung'

class SadrAdresse(models.Model):
    adr_adrid = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    adr_name1 = models.CharField(max_length=35, blank=True, null=True)
    adr_name2 = models.CharField(max_length=35, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'sadr_adresse'
```

## Sample Data

SsdaSdgadr:

| sdg_sdgid | sda_satid | sda_adrid | sda_ref | sda_termvon | sda_termbis |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BL-1237781-BL-1 | IV | 169550 | '00123/4539999' | '' | '' |
| BL-1237781-BL-1 | SU | 555555 | '' | 01.12.2021 | 02.12.2021 |
| BL-1237781-BL-1 | CN | 999999 | '00123' | 02.12.2021 | 13.12.2021 |

## views.py

I used following raw SQL

```
    Sendungen = SsdaSdgadr.objects.raw('''
        SELECT 
            IV.id,
            IV.sda_sdgid_id,
            IV.sda_ref,
            SU.id,
            SU.sda_adrid_id as ABS,
            SU.sda_termvon,
            CN.id,
            CN.sda_adrid_id as EMPF,
            CN.sda_termbis
        FROM 
            ssda_sdgadr IV
            INNER JOIN ssdg_sendung on sdg_sdgid = IV.sda_sdgid_id
            INNER JOIN ssda_sdgadr SU on SU.sda_sdgid_id = IV.sda_sdgid_id and SU.sda_satid="SU"
            INNER JOIN ssda_sdgadr CN on CN.sda_sdgid_id = IV.sda_sdgid_id and CN.sda_satid="CN"
        WHERE IV.sda_satid="IV"
        GROUP BY
            IV.id,
            IV.sda_sdgid_id,
            IV.sda_ref,
            SU.id,
            SU.sda_adrid_id,
            SU.sda_termvon,
            CN.id,
            CN.sda_adrid_id,
            CN.sda_termbis
        ORDER BY
            sdg_datum desc
    ''')
...
response = render(request, 'cust/home.html', {
            'Sendungen': Sendungen,
        })
return response
```

The result on the template works fine for the fields "SU.sda_termvon" & "CN.sda_termbis", but does not work for the field "sda_adrid" (→ Only the the result for IV.sda_adrid_id is displayed).

## Template code

```
 {% for la_item in Sendungen %}
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{ la_item.sda_sdgid.sdg_sdgid }}</td>
                            <td>{{ la_item.sda_ref }}</td> <!-- IV.sda_ref OKAY -->
                            <td>{{ la_item.sda_adrid.adr_adrid }}</td> <!-- is IV.sda_adrid NOT OKAY -->
                            <td>{{ la_item.sda_adrid.adr_adrid }}</td> <!-- is IV.sda_adrid NOT OKAY -->
                            <td>{{ la_item.sda_termvon|date }}</td> <!-- SU.sda_termvon OKAY -->
                            <td>{{ la_item.sda_termbis|date }}</td> <!-- CN.sda_termbis OKAY -->
                        </tr>
 {% endfor %}
```

How can I access to the results "CN.sda_adrid_id" & "SU.sda_adrid_id" on template?
→ It look like that the ORM interprets the raw-SQL different than the database:

DB-Result & Desired result should look like this:

| sda_sdgid_id | IV.sda_ref | SU.sda_adrid_id | CN.sda_adrid | SU.termvon | CN.termbis |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BL-1237781-BL-1 | 1920192/4530210220/0881760357 | 555555 | 999999 | 01.12.2021 | 13.12.2021 |

My actual result look like this:

| sda_sdgid_id | IV.sda_ref | IV.sda_adrid_id | IV.sda_adrid_id | SU.termvon | CN.termbis |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BL-1237781-BL-1 | 1920192/4530210220/0881760357 | 169550 | 169550 | 01.12.2021 | 13.12.2021 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this workaround (model property for "SsdaSdgadr"), which gave me the desired result:

## models.py

```
class SsdaSdgadr(models.Model):
    sda_sdgid = models.ForeignKey(SsdgSendung, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    sda_satid = models.CharField(max_length=4, blank=True, null=True)
    sda_adrid = models.ForeignKey(SadrAdresse, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    sda_ref = models.CharField(max_length=35, blank=True, null=True)
    sda_termbis = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    sda_termvon = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'ssda_sdgadr'
        unique_together = (('sda_sdgid', 'sda_satid'),)

    @property
    def is_adr_su(self):
        return  SsdaSdgadr.objects.filter(sda_sdgid = self.sda_sdgid, sda_satid = "SU")

    @property
    def is_adr_cn(self):
        return  SsdaSdgadr.objects.filter(sda_sdgid = self.sda_sdgid, sda_satid = "CN")
```

## views.py

```
Sendungen = SsdaSdgadr.objects.filter(Q(sda_satid__in=["IV"])).order_by('-sda_sdgid__sdg_datum')
...
response = render(request, 'cust/home.html', {
            'Sendungen': Sendungen,
        })
return response
```

## Template code home.html

```
{% for la_item in Sendungen %}
<tr>
 <td>{{ la_item.sda_sdgid.sdg_sdgid }}</td>
 <td>{{ la_item.sda_ref }}</td> <!-- IV.sda_ref OKAY -->
 {% for adr in la_item.is_adr_su %}
   <td>{{ adr.sda_adrid.adr_adrid }}</td> <!-- SU.sda_adrid OKAY -->
   <td>{{ adr.sda_termvon|date }}</td> <!-- SU.sda_termvon OKAY -->
 {% endfor %}
 {% for adr in la_item.is_adr_cn %}
   <td>{{ adr.sda_adrid.adr_adrid }}</td> <!-- CN.sda_adrid OKAY -->
   <td>{{ adr.sda_termbis|date }}</td> <!-- CN.sda_termbis OKAY -->
 {% endfor %}
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```